# No module named 'pymata4'

Tags: python-3.x

I need to know why I have an error when I do `from pymata4 import pymata4` once I installed pymata4 by `pip3 install pymata4` for python3.

The error is: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pymata4'`.

Thank you for help.

Comment: which python version ? I can't reproduce that error, with `Python 3.12.1` your import line works for me.

Comment: I resolved it by `import sys
sys.path.append("/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages")
from pymata4 import pymata4`
Thank you.